# Use c string to send multiple null characters. ASCII Armoring

Tags: c, ascii

How to use a C string to contain multiple null characters \x00.

Answer (score 9):

C's string functions (eg `strlen()`, `printf()`, etc) assume that the buffer will be null-terminated. If you have a buffer with multiple 0x00 characters, then you can't use any functions which treat 0x00 as a null character.

So instead of using, eg, `strcpy()` (or `strncpy()`) you would use `memcpy()` - to move the bytes of memory from one place to another, rather than relying on this null-terminated behavior.

Answer (score 3):

A C string is only an array of chars terminated by a null character. However, if you treat it as an array, it can contain inner null characters:

```
char data[4] = { 'x', '\0', 'y', '\0' };
```

You have to be careful, however, as most of the standard library functions will not work, as they expect an C string ending with the first null character.

For example, `strlen(data)` will return 1 in the example above, as it stops after the first null character.

Comment: Ehm, it is true that a C string is only an array of char, but it is specifically defined in C that a string is terminated by a `\0` character. So technically, anything after a termination character is not part of a C string. If, on the other hand, you treat the array as an array, then yes, you can stick whatever char-size elements you like in it. You just can't use it as a string any longer.

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is something like

```
char* data = (char*)malloc( 8 ) ; // allocate space for 8 bytes
memset( data, 0, 8 ) ; // set all 8 bytes to 0's
```